# Why does the QnaMakerDialog have no a built-in virtual task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync?

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am following a [tutorial](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/08/25/qna-maker-rich-card-attachments-net/) from microsoft's blog while building a chatbot and using QnAMaker. I am now working on adding a `RichCard`.

I need to override one method from the built-in `QnAMakerDialog` and so I could modify that method from my new class `QnaDialog`.

In the code given in the tutorial, there is already a function `protected virtual Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync` in the built-in `QnAMakerDialog`

The whole code sample in there looks like this :

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker
{
    // Summary:
    //     A dialog specialized to handle QnA response from QnA Maker.
    public class QnAMakerDialog : IDialog<IMessageActivity>
    {
        protected readonly IQnAService[] services;
        public QnAMakerDialog(params IQnAService[] services);
        public IQnAService[] MakeServicesFromAttributes();
        public Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument);
        protected virtual Task DefaultWaitNextMessageAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result);
        protected virtual bool IsConfidentAnswer(QnAMakerResults qnaMakerResults);
        protected virtual Task QnAFeedbackStepAsync(IDialogContext context, QnAMakerResults qnaMakerResults);
        protected virtual Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result);
    }
}
```

However, in my actual case the code in the QnAMakerDialog is just this:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker
{
    public class QnAMakerDialog : IDialog<IMessageActivity>
    {
        protected readonly IQnAService[] services;

        public QnAMakerDialog(params IQnAService[] services);

        public IQnAService[] MakeServicesFromAttributes();
        [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<MessageReceivedAsync>d__4))]
        public Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument);
    }
}
```

And the problem is, the code above located in my QnAMakerDialog is not editable.

Do I have some more things to install from my nuggets package? or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial you are using?

Comment: I already add the link. @DFBerry

Comment: @PearlyJaneMercado could you try removing the botbuilder-cognitive services nuget package and re-install, then clean/re-build your project? I'm unable to reproduce your problem. [QnaMakerDialog.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs) most recent version is there, as you can see RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync is there.